# How to close ASPSessionId in a Visual Studio Web/Performance Test

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, testing, load, session-cookies

I have finally given up on this and I'm looking for some help on this.  Here is what I have found so far.

First of all, web performance tests and/or load tests in visual studio do NOT use the browser (during playback it's not used, but it is used during the recording of the test) which is when/where the ASPSessionId is stored in a cookie or form post parameter.

I have web performance tests that have extraction rules to get the ASPSessionID from the server which I try to set in a later request as header/form post parameter, however this doesn't seem to help and it appears that I am just using the same one over and over causing the server to respond differently (presents different pages)

On the system I am testing a user will go to the site and fill out an application.  If the user is in the same session the user can fill out multiple subsequent applications and have the ability to re-use some data.  If that is true, the user is presented a page to select the re-usable data.  If the session is new the user does not get to do this.

If I play the web test over and over manually, it works as expected (new session ID, no re-use data page presented).  However, if I play that same test over and over in a load test, the first time it will pass and each time after it fails, because the session is kept open and then the server provides different pages than the ones that exist in my web performance test.  The failures on the subsequent applications includes fails like (expected response URL, extraction rules...etc)

So I was using an extraction rule to get the ASPSessionID from the server and store it in a cookie and/or web form post parameters and then set it, but it is not working.

What can I do in the web performance test to successfully close the ASPSessionID so that the test runs like it is running for the first time in the load test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the LoadTest Test Mix, set the "Percentage of New Users" to 100.  That completely solved it for me.

Comment: This worked for me and I also have created a web test plugin (Pre webtest plugin) that deletes the cookies before each new session is started.